# Downloading A Picture of an individual Instagram post with with Instaloader and Python

Tags: python, instagram-api, imagedownload, instaloader

Using Python and the Instaloader package I am able to to download A profile Picture via this code

```
import instaloader
        dp = instaloader.Instaloader()
        dp.download_profile(profile_name, profile_pic_only = True)
```

All I have to do is provide the profile name.

What I also want to archive is, I want to download the picture of an individual post, such as: https://www.instagram.com/p/CgbAU5GD6MU/

Can this be done with Python instaloader?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure! Get the urls you want and easily use them

```py
import instaloader

L = instaloader.Instaloader()
post_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/CgbAU5GD6MU/'
post = instaloader.Post.from_shortcode(L.context, post_url.split('p/')[1].strip('/ '))
photo_url = post.url   # this will be post's thumbnail (or first slide)
video_url = post.video_url  # if post.is_video is True then it will be url of video file
```

Comment: Hi realSamy,
Thanks a lot for this quick and helpful response. 
Since I need need to build a wesbite similiar to this "https://en.savefrom.net/135/download-from-instagram", performance is important. 
I only need the post pic, not the complete post with comments, likes and hashtags. Is there an option, such as "post_pic_only=True"?

Comment: Edited, now it works as you want

Comment: Wow, thanks for the aweseome help! However, this is only working, if I add the following line below the line where we instantiating the loader:
"L.login(username,password")"
Without the line, I get this Error:
  raise LoginRequiredException("Redirected to login page. Use --login.")
instaloader.exceptions.LoginRequiredException: Redirected to login page. Use --login.
""
The strange thing is, downloading the profile or just the profile_pic as described above works without this line.

Comment: seems instagram has some limits on using it without login, you may use an account to handle your project's needs